# Re-Installing GarageBand from iLife '11 DVD (Guitar Tracks Issue)

Tags: ilife, garageband

Due to an issue regarding the creation of Guitar Tracks in GarageBand '11, and that none of the reported fixes ([here](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3664?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) and [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2718614?start=0&tstart=0)) have worked, I am looking to re-install.  However, I don't appear to be able to re-install just GarageBand '11 from my iLife DVD.  I have navigated to the 'Customize' part of the installer, however it greys out the tick boxes for iLife Support, iPhoto, iMovie and iDVD (both skipped by default), and GarageBand.

I don't want to re-install iPhoto, nor anything else other than GarageBand and because I have bought a retail version of iLife '11 I don't think I can download from the App Store.  Given that an App Store download was one of the known causes, then this wouldn't be appropriate anyway.

Of course, if someone has a proven fix for my problem other than those mentioned then I would also find that acceptable :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might try installing Pacifist - it allows you to get inside apple's installer packages and install individual items

http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/6812/pacifist

Comment: This is helpful, thanks.  Though, I would rather not install an extra program to un-install then re-install a different program!  If this is my only option though, then that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with GB 09' and after hours and days of testing, I remember I removed GB (manually removed the Apk and all the ~/library folders associated with GB. After that I was able to reinstall it.

Just in case, move everything to another folder as a Backup. After you remove the program from your /Applications, iLife should allow you to be able to reinstall it.

Comment: I had this thought too, however as stated, the Installer also greys out iPhoto which I don't want to re-install as it is working correctly.

Comment: If I were you I'd remove iLife completely and reinstall. Your libraries do not get removed in the process and you end up with a fresh copy of everything. You sound rather afraid of installing software, don't be, it's quite easy to remove and leave no trace, OS X doesn't have a registry :)

Comment: Well, I'm not afraid per se...just that I always live by the 'If it ain't broke, don't fix it' mantra.  I'll try a full un-install, thanks.

Comment: Excellent, let us know how it went, should you still experience the same problem. Good luck!